# Aero bug in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, aero, visual-artifacts

Have you seen anything like this before?

[image]

Not always but permanently shows up this strange behavior. What's the name of that problem? And how can I solve it?

**I tried:**

- driver update
- full driver/app uninstall and Lenovo ThingVantage System Update
- turning aero off (... and everything works fine)
- monitor driver update (but only generic PNP monitor found)

**Configuration**:

- Lenovo Thinkpad T400s (was Vista but clean Windows 7 install now) (update: this is **not** a lenovo specific error)
- Windows 7 Professional (ENG)
- Mobile Inter 45 Express (WDDM 1.1)

**Update**

I found the 'correct' name: visual corruption.

The problem appears when **VT-d technology is enabled** (ie. for VPC). Turn off and hopfully everything will work fine. Details: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-7-Discussion/Bizarre-screen-artifacts-on-R400-Integrated-Graphics-running-Win/m-p/199594. In short: go to BIOS and disable it.

**Update II**

Just for google:) It's hard to characterize the problem so there are some keywords for it:

*aero, glitches, pixel, bug, visual corruption, garbled textures, frame error, virtualization, vt-d*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to check the current temperature of your GPU, when this happens. You can use something like [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) (or another recommended at [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature)).

To me, it looks like artifacts which occurs when the graphical card is heating too much. Since Aero is relying on more advanced graphics than a regular desktop display, it could explain why such thing happens only with it. This thought is also seconded by the fact that you report such problem happening only from time to time.

For information, you can find examples of such graphical glitches happening [at this link](http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?p=3225333) (too big images to copy here).

Comment: thank you, the last link helped to solve the problem! edited my post to clarify.

Comment: @boj - my answer only pointed you in good direction, it doesn't actually answer the problem. You should write the answer yourself, with exactly what fixed it, and accept it (you can't accept your own answer before 2 days, though). It would make it probably more clear. Finally, my answer is only about heat, nothing really linked.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem with my Dell Latitude XT-2. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/45296/display-glitches-in-windows-7-on-dell-latitude-xt2). And yes, it was the same underlying issue.

Comment: thanx, I'll collect the adjectives in my post to help others find it.

Comment: Somehow I have doubts that the words in your post will do anything to make it more findable.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this happens if you use a mismatched (1GB + 2GB) pair of memory modules. Lenovo has a support page for the problem:

> http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-74739&selectarea=SUPPORT&tempselected=5

I have the exact same problem and VD-t off solves it. Cheaper than upgrading to 4GB of RAM. :)