# Are there any downsides to enabling Hardware Virtualization in the BIOS?

Tags: security, cpu, virtualization, bios

I was wondering if there are any downsides (even theoretical) to enabling Hardware Virtualization in the BIOS.  I noticed that it is disabled by default, and perhaps it is that way for a reason although I can't think of a good one.

My computer is an Intel-based (i7 QuadCore) HP EliteBook laptop, but I'm more interested in the general case.

Comment: There's this [question where enabling hardware virtualization caused display glitches](http://superuser.com/questions/45296/display-glitches-in-windows-7-on-dell-latitude-xt2)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One reason is security.

Root kits could use it to gain higher access to hardware than OS. Setting it to disabled mitigates this risk (see [analysis](https://web.archive.org/web/20121130215423/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463498.aspx)).

Answer (score 10):

Performance-wise? No.

Security-wise? See @Josip's answer (which I've upvoted, btw)

However, common malwares can't yet leverage the virtualization extension. And if you use your computer safely (e.g., run as a regular user instead of an administrator-level one), the risks are practically mitigated.

That said, if you want to run virtual machines, Virtualization Extensions (Intel VT-x or AMD-V) will help increase performance significantly.

Comment: Hi Pepoluan, could you please provide some background or references in regard to your statement that performance is not affected? I don't have any specific reason to doubt but I believe this would be a better answer if it included an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: It has been quite some time since I did the research (note the date of my answer), so unfortunately I can no longer find the reference. IIRC, it's a discussion topic in the Xen mailing list.