# What is VT-x? Why it is not enabled in few machine by default

Tags: virtual-machine, bios, vt-x

While installing Virtual machine I am getting error that VT-x is not enabled so I am not able to continue install Virtual OS.

So

1. What is VT-x?
2. How to enable it?
3. By enabling will cause performance of machine?

Comment: @Moab Why not post your comment as an answer with a brief summary

Comment: Done as you asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel Virtualization Technology (VT). Formerly known as Vanderpool, this technology enables a CPU to act as if you have several independent computers, in order to enable several operating systems to run at the same time on the same machine. In this tutorial we will explain everything you need to know about this technology.
Intel’s virtualization technology is available in two versions: VT-x, for x86 processors; and VT-i, for Itanium (i.e., IA-64) processors. In this tutorial we will be covering the details of the VT-x technology.

[Source](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-intel-virtualization-technology/)

VT-x is enabled in the bios if the bios and motherboard support it
[Example](https://superuser.com/questions/592840/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x?rq=1)

No it will not hurt performance if it is enabled, most PC's have it disabled in the bios by default.

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/24684/are-there-any-good-reasons-for-disabling-hardware-assisted-virtualization)

Comment: Okay but _why_ is it disabled by default?

Comment: it can be used by malicious code, so it is disabled by default for security reasons, every pc I bought has it disabled by default....http://serverfault.com/a/24691

Comment: and this...http://superuser.com/questions/273656/are-there-any-downsides-to-enabling-hardware-virtualization-in-the-bios